# S6 Duos: Toggle for Data Service Network

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6, dual-sim

I have a **Samsung Galaxy S6 Duos**, with two SIM cards set up. Each of them has a data plan. In order to switch the active data plans from one SIM to another, I go to *SIM Card Manager* under *Settings* and change the preferred SIM for *Mobile Data Network*. Is there a more convenient way to do this?

I can switch between active SIMs using the pull-down menu, but this does not switch the active data connection. Is there a setting or utility that lets me do this from the pull-down menu as well?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the dual SIM Samsung devices, changing the active SIM does not change the Data Network SIM same time. You need to go to Settings and change the mobile data network. 
As a quick shortcut, you can touch and hold the Data Network button from the pull down menu and it will open the Data Network settings. Then you can switch the SIM for the data network.